# How to find the proportion of time that values were greater than x, in R?

Tags: r, date, time

I have a dataframe with date/time series and I am trying to find the monthly amount of time that values were above > x (for the purpose of this question lets say > 5).

Here is a sample dataframe

```
# Create a, b, c, d variables
a <- c("06-25-20 08:00:00 AM","06-25-20 08:15:00 AM",
       "06-25-20 08:30:00 AM","06-25-20 08:45:00 AM",
       "07-25-20 08:45:00 AM", "07-25-20 08:45:00 AM",
       "08-25-20 08:45:00 AM", "08-25-20 08:45:00 AM",
       "09-25-20 08:45:00 AM","09-25-20 08:45:00 AM")
b <- c(4,5,8, "N/A", 4,5,"N/A",7,7,6)
c <- c(6,10,8, "N/A", 8,5,"N/A",8,7,2)
# Join the variables to create a data frame
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)
df$a = as.POSIXlt(df$a, format="%m-%d-%y%H:%M:%S", tz = 'EST')
```

I started by separating the date and time

```
#Put date and time into seperate columns
df$Day <- as.Date(stewiacke_WA$a)
df$Time <- format(df$b,"%H:%M:%S")
```

There are 2 problems I'm left with. Firstly, the `Time` column is `class(character)` and when I use the code

```
df$Time = as.POSIXct(df$Time, format = "%H:%M:%S", tz = 'EST')
```

the `Time` column adds back on the dates.

My second issue, is that I don't know how to calculate the monthly amount of time that each column values were > 5. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The `lubridate` package is very helpful when working with dates and times.
I’ll also use `dplyr` for calculating the time per month of `b` or `c` being above `5`.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

# Create a, b, c, d variables
a <- c(
  "06-25-20 08:00:00 AM",
  "06-25-20 08:15:00 AM",
  "06-25-20 08:30:00 AM",
  "06-25-20 08:45:00 AM",
  "07-25-20 08:45:00 AM",
  "07-25-20 08:45:00 AM",
  "08-25-20 08:45:00 AM",
  "08-25-20 08:45:00 AM",
  "09-25-20 08:45:00 AM",
  "09-25-20 08:45:00 AM"
)
```

When defining missing values in your data make sure to use `NA` not `"N/A"`!

```r
b <- c(4, 5, 8, NA, 4, 5, NA, 7, 7, 6)
c <- c(6, 10, 8, NA, 8, 5, NA, 8, 7, 2)
```

`tibble()` instead of `data.frame()` makes it easier to see the class of the columns.

```r
df <-
  tibble(a, b, c) 

df$a = as.POSIXlt(df$a, format = "%m-%d-%y%H:%M:%S", tz = 'EST')

df$month <- month(df$a)
```

Time per month of `b` being bigger than five for each month

```r
df %>%
  group_by(month) %>% 
  mutate(prev_a = lag(a, 1),
         diff_time = a - prev_a) %>% 
  filter(b > 5) %>% 
  summarise(sum_diff_time = sum(diff_time, na.rm = TRUE))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   month sum_diff_time
#>   <dbl> <drtn>       
#> 1     6 900 secs     
#> 2     8   0 secs     
#> 3     9   0 secs
```

And the same for `c`

```r
df %>%
  group_by(month) %>% 
  mutate(prev_a = lag(a, 1),
         diff_time = a - prev_a) %>% 
  filter(c > 5) %>% 
  summarise(sum_diff_time = sum(diff_time, na.rm = TRUE))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   month sum_diff_time
#>   <dbl> <drtn>       
#> 1     6 1800 secs    
#> 2     7    0 secs    
#> 3     8    0 secs    
#> 4     9    0 secs
```

Note: This assumes that the values for `b` and `c` are the same at the time
`a` and the previous value of `a`. I guess your are looking for a result that
is somewhat different from that, but this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: So the first part works, but as for the proportion of b over 5... I'm actually looking for the proportion of time that b > 5

Comment: I am nut sure if I fully understand what you are looking for. So, if to consecutive timestamps have a `b` value above 5 the time between the two time stamps would be counted as above 5? What if there is a single timestamp above 5 but before and after it his below 5? How would that be counted? If you could update your question to be more explicit about this I can take a look.

Comment: Just edited it. Basically, I want to know how much time in a month was b > 5

Comment: I don't see any relevant updates to the question. The problem I  have with the way you are asking the question right now is that it can be interpreted in many ways. The data you have are timestamped snapshots, but you are looking for a result that is based on assumptions on what is happening between/before/after these timestamps. As long as I don't know these assumptions I am not sure how to best answer your question.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.

Comment: I updated my answer based on the most likely / simple assumption. I hope it helps to point you in the right direction.